# normal Button with onclick event inside a form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, button

i tried to add a  inside a formular. This button is connected with a javascript per onclick event.

so i made the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
<fieldset>
<div id="table_output"></div>
<legend>Behandlungstremin</legend>
<button name="add_termin" id="add_termin" onclick="add_termin()">+ Termin</button>
</fieldset>
<br>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Rechnug erstellen" name="submit" id="submit">
</div>
<script>
    function add_termin() {
    document.getElementById("table_output").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

if i run this code in my browser the Hello World text disapears after a secound.

can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have an idea of how form submission works? Remove the `form` and use a click handler when you don't need the form.

Comment: @teemu Do all buttons submit forms when they are inside of the form?

Comment: i need the form for posting the entries in php

Comment: @jsve Yes, that's a default action, and especially for a button type of `submit` ; ).

Comment: @look001 Your form tag doesn't look like you'd use it for that purpose.

Comment: oh thanks so much :) finaly i used a normal text instead of a button

Comment: @Teemu, the OP is talking about the `<button>` with the `onclick` event, not the `submit` input.

Comment: @jsve Yeah, I noticed that, but what has been said stands, the default action of a `<button>` (which is not type of `button`) within a `form`, is to submit a form.

Comment: @jsve See [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON): "submit: Creates a submit button. This is the default value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <div id="table_output">hgfdx</div>
            <legend>Behandlungstremin</legend>
            <button name="add_termin" id="add_termin" onclick="addTermin()" type="button">+ Termin</button>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Rechnug erstellen" name="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    <script>
        function addTermin()
        {
            document.getElementById("table_output").innerHTML="Hello World";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You missed the **type="button"** attribute..